# Extracting a subset of records for every entry based on value

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I am new to unix. I have tab delim txt file as follows:

```
ID     Region Strt End Length
sd_2_1 head   241   930 689
sd_2_1 trunk  16    240 224
sd_2_1 tail    1    15  14

sd_2_1 head    1    1   0
sd_2_1 trunk   2    832 830
sd_2_1 tail   833   930 97

sd_2_1 head   780   930 150
sd_2_1 trunk  663   779 116
sd_2_1 tail   1     662 661

sd_3_1 head  1020   1649 629
sd_3_1 trunk 783    1019 236
sd_3_1 tail   1     782  781

sd_3_1 trunk  1     1470 1469
sd_3_1 tail  1471   1649 178  

sd_4_1 head   2      50   48
sd_4_1 trunk  51     701  650

sd_4_1 head   1      40   38
sd_4_1 trunk  41     101  60
sd_4_1 tail   102    122  20
```

Every Id multiple subset of regions with different entries(separated by space) I want compare the the every ID with its own subset and retain only the the subset for every ID which has maximum trunk length. In the end I would like to obtain the file like follows:

```
      ID     Region Strt End Length
  sd_2_1      head    1    1   0
  sd_2_1      trunk   2    832 830
  sd_2_1      tail   833   930 97

  sd_3_1      trunk  1     1470 1469
  sd_3_1      tail   1471  1649 178 

  sd_4_1       head   2      50   48
  sd_4_1       trunk  51     701  650
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Kindly guide me

Comment: why in output there is no `head` line for `sd_3_1`? and no `tail` line for `sd_4_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the perl version

```
while(<>) { 
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ /(head|trunk|tail)/) {
        # Parse and store the relevant lines
        ($id, $region, $start, $end, $length) = split;
        $entry{$region} = $_;
        if($region eq "trunk") {
            $trunklength = $length;
        }
    } elsif(defined ($id)) {
        # Check if this is the greatest trunk length
        if($trunklength > $trunklength{$id}) {
            # Clear old values
            $trunklength{$id}= $trunklength;
            undef($trunklength);
            # Store new values
            $trunk{$id} = $entry{"trunk"};
            $head{$id} = $entry{"head"};
            $tail{$id} = $entry{"tail"};
        }
        undef %entry;
    }
}
# Print out the answer
foreach $id (sort (keys(%trunklength))) {
    print "$head{$id}\n" if (defined($head{$id}));
    print "$trunk{$id}\n" if (defined($trunk{$id}));
    print "$tail{$id}\n" if (defined($tail{$id}));
    print "\n";
}
```

It starts by parsing the head, start and tail lines storing them in a hash indexed by the region.  The trunklength is stored.  On a blank line, the trunklength is compared with the stored trunklength for the id.  If it is greater than the previous values for head, trunk and length are discarded and replaced with the current versions.  This caters for the case where some values are absent.

Finally loop through the hashes to print out the required values.  Note that perl does the obvious thing for uninitialized variables so there is no need to check for `$trunklength{id}` not being set for example.

Comment: I have modified the answer by removing some unnecessary `undef` calls as eg `$head{$id} = $entry{"head"};` will overwrite `$head{$id}}` with an undefined value if a new head entry has not been set.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ (head -1 file && sed 1d file
    | awk -v RS= '{len=0; 
                   for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=5) 
                      if($i=="trunk") {len=$(i+3); break} 
                   if(len>v[$1]) {v[$1]=len; r[$1]=$0}
                  } 
               END{for(k in r) print r[k]}') 
    | column -t

ID      Region  Strt  End   Length
sd_2_1  head    1     1     0
sd_2_1  trunk   2     832   830
sd_2_1  tail    833   930   97
sd_3_1  trunk   1     1470  1469
sd_3_1  tail    1471  1649  178
sd_4_1  head    2     50    48
sd_4_1  trunk   51    701   650
```

Subshell is to separate the header from the body for processing.  Set the record separator to paragraph mode, find the corresponding length for each record (since some lines might be missing there is little complexity). Pick the maximum value for each key and print when done.

If you need spacing between different ID rows.

```
... | column -t | awk 'NR<3{p=$1} $1!=p{print "";p=$1} 1'

ID      Region  Strt  End   Length
sd_2_1  head    1     1     0
sd_2_1  trunk   2     832   830
sd_2_1  tail    833   930   97

sd_3_1  trunk   1     1470  1469
sd_3_1  tail    1471  1649  178

sd_4_1  head    2     50    48
sd_4_1  trunk   51    701   650
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no input file specified for awk.
   awk -F "\t" '{if($5==max)}' ???

It should have been awk -F "\t" '{if($5==max)}' infile.txt

Or if you are supposing to get it from previously piped process, I hope you have used xargs command for substituting max.

2. What are you trying to search in grep? You have not given a pattern
3. Your awk doesn't print anything. I am assuming this is a one time requirement and that you are already aware of max value,.

   Your command should look like

`awk '{if($5==max1 || $5==max2 || $5==max3){ print $5 }}' infile.txt | sed 's/ /|/g' | xargs -ipattern grep -C 1 'pattern' >out.txt`

-> Here i am converting the multi-line output from awk using sed and have used xargs to pass pattern to grep

 -> Here, if max1,2,3 are not unique numbers in entire file, this command will break.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your comment. Actually I want to retain only one susbet which has maximum trunk length among others and print it along with head and tail. For an example sd_2_1 has 3 subsets with different trunk length, I would like print only the susbset which has maximum trunk length. Kindly guide me

Comment: Yes, By max 1,2 and 3, I mean max values of sd_2_1,sd_3_1 and sd_4_1 respectively. So, it prints highest subset of sd_2_1,sd_3_1,sd_4_1